# ROR error with Salesforce: The requested resource does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, salesforce, databasedotcom-gem

I am using the Ruby Gem "databascdotcom" to integrate Salesforce in a Rails app and all works fine.

But getting following error on first call to salesforce:

> **The requested resource does not exist**

If I refresh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) the page again, it works fine without any error.

Here is my code:

```
def SalesForceFeed
  @oppID = params[:oppid]

  client = Databasedotcom::Client.new client.client_id #=> foo client.client_secret #=> bar
  client.authenticate :username => "foo@bar.com", :password => "ThePasswordTheSecurityToken" #=> "the-oauth-token"
  client.materialize("Opportunity")
  begin
      @client=SalesForce::Connection.new.client
      @opp = Opportunity.find_by_Id(@oppID)
  rescue Exception=>e
    if(e.message == "The requested resource does not exist")
      return redirect_to :action => 'SalesForceFeed', :oppid => @oppID
    end
  end
```

On the first call to "SalesForceFeed" it returned the error "The requested resource does not exist", so I added an excepton check and called "SalesForceFeed" again, but I know this is not the right way.

Please suggest me a better way to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: finally i got the issue, there was a wrong object added in materialize, i removed that and its fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the issue.  There was a wrong object added in materialize.  I removed that and it's fixed.

Comment: awesome! You know that you can your own reply as the answer so that others can benefit.

Comment: can you write code of you mistake like before and after style?

Comment: client.materialize("Opportunity") was mistakenly written as client.materialize("Opportuniti"), so object name was wrong and giving error