# Databasedotcom::SalesForceError Error The requested resource does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, databasedotcom-gem

Does any body else here know better why this error occurs?

Databasedotcom::SalesForceError
Error
The requested resource does not exist
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/databasedotcom-8666381d50b7/lib/databasedotcom/client.rb:376:in `ensure_expected_response'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/databasedotcom-8666381d50b7/lib/databasedotcom/client.rb:334:in`with_encoded_path_and_checked_response'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/databasedotcom-8666381d50b7/lib/databasedotcom/client.rb:326:in `http_multipart_post'

I searched but [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976343/databasedotcom-error-on-no-record-found) and [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666759/ror-error-with-salesforce-the-requested-resource-does-not-exist) does not help here!

Comment: What is the actual question? When does this error happen?

Comment: It's pretty random, let's say 99% of the time I am just able to connect via Databasedotcom gem, and process the data (read+write). It maybe irrelevant but the code is run from resque workers running in the app which is deployed on Heroku. The resque workers keep on processing the data every minute. And in some rare situations i see that error. I am not sure why and when would this error happen!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's got to be the issue with stale session in Force.com API.

In my rails app I login multiple times in SFDC, each time using different user credentials, and authenticate the databasedotcom gem using the Oauth token received.

I am facing some issues due to this supposed stale sessions:
[using multiple access tokens with databasedotcom gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718005/using-multiple-access-tokens-with-databasedotcom-gem)

Need to find a way to invalidate/expire the oauth authentication for one user before trying to authenticate using another user.